# How to remove axis and scale plot to occupy entire space in 3d plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So far I have been able to produce the following plot:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    view={80}{30},
    axis equal,
    hide axis
    ]
    
    \addplot3[
    dashed,
    y domain=0:0,
    samples=200,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    ]
    ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
    
    \addplot3[
    thick,
    y domain=0:0,
    samples=200,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    ]
    ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0.3*sin(deg(7*x))});
    
    \addplot3[
    y domain=0:0,
    samples=200,
    domain=0:2*pi,
    ]
    ({1+0.1*cos(deg(x))},{0.1*sin(deg(x))},{0});
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is just a very long sentence. I want my graph to extend through the entire space available; nonetheless, there is a white space occupied by the axis I want to remove.}
    \label{fig:motion}
\end{figure}
```

which produces the following (almos exactly what I want):

[image: What I have]

I was able to hide the axis, but the space they occupied is still there. I would want my plot to extend through the entire horizontal length available (and hopefully be able to control it).

The final plot I want would be something like the following:

[image: What I want]

I would also want to include the arrows and text text to each path. But my main question is about the size, I can google around how to add these later if they are not trivial.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width can be increased by increasing the `width`. Since you suppress the frame, the value that is required to get the full width is a bit counterintuitive but perhaps simpler than playing with the other keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=1.25\textwidth,
    view={80}{30},
    axis equal image,
    hide axis,sp/.style={smooth cycle,
    samples y=0,domain=#1,
    samples=101},sp/.default=0:2*pi
    ]    
    \addplot3[sp,dashed] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
    
    \addplot3[sp,thick] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0.3*sin(deg(7*x))});
    
    \addplot3[sp,thin] ({1+0.1*cos(deg(x))},{0.1*sin(deg(x))},{0});
    
    \addplot3[sp=pi-0.4:pi-0.05,sharp plot,red,-{Stealth}] 
        ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{-0.1})
        node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily,below]{Magnetron};
    \addplot3[sp=-0.7:-0.5,sharp plot,red,-{Stealth}] 
        ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0.3*sin(deg(7*x))+0.1})
        node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily,above right]{Axial};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is just a very long sentence. I want my graph to extend through the entire space available; nonetheless, there is a white space occupied by the axis I want to remove.}
    \label{fig:motion}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought that `[scale only axis]` could handle the width, but it still leaves room for the entire cube (domain) in which points are drawn.  About the only way to fix this is retroactively using `\resizebox`, which will also make the fonts slightly larger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis, width=\textwidth,
    view={80}{30},
    axis equal image,
    hide axis,
    sp/.style={smooth cycle,
    samples y=0,domain=#1,
    samples=101},sp/.default=0:2*pi
    ]    
    \addplot3[sp,dashed] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
    
    \addplot3[sp,thick] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0.3*sin(deg(7*x))});
    
    \addplot3[sp,thin] ({1+0.1*cos(deg(x))},{0.1*sin(deg(x))},{0});
    
    \addplot3[sp=pi-0.4:pi-0.05,sharp plot,red,-{Stealth}] 
        ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{-0.1})
        node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily,below]{Magnetron};
    \addplot3[sp=-0.7:-0.5,sharp plot,red,-{Stealth}] 
        ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0.3*sin(deg(7*x))+0.1})
        node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily,above right]{Axial};
    \end{axis}
    \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \caption{This is just a very long sentence. I want my graph to extend through the entire space available; nonetheless, there is a white space occupied by the axis I want to remove.}
    \label{fig:motion}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

If you don't want to change the font size, you can compute the width needed by doing the graph twice.

Note that `\redo`, `\scale` and `\box0` are local to the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\redo{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scale only axis, width=\scale\textwidth,
    view={80}{30},
    axis equal image,
    hide axis,
    sp/.style={smooth cycle,
    samples y=0,domain=#1,
    samples=101},sp/.default=0:2*pi
    ]    
    \addplot3[sp,dashed] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0});
    
    \addplot3[sp,thick] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0.3*sin(deg(7*x))});
    
    \addplot3[sp,thin] ({1+0.1*cos(deg(x))},{0.1*sin(deg(x))},{0});
    
    \addplot3[sp=pi-0.4:pi-0.05,sharp plot,red,-{Stealth}] 
        ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{-0.1})
        node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily,below]{Magnetron};
    \addplot3[sp=-0.7:-0.5,sharp plot,red,-{Stealth}] 
        ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{0.3*sin(deg(7*x))+0.1})
        node[pos=0.5,font=\sffamily,above right]{Axial};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \sbox0{\def\scale{1}\redo}% get width for scale=1
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{\textwidth/\wd0}% recompute scale
    \redo    
    \caption{This is just a very long sentence. I want my graph to extend through the entire space available; nonetheless, there is a white space occupied by the axis I want to remove.}
    \label{fig:motion}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```